# Is there a compatibility issue between macros written for XLS, XLSX and XLSM?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a compatibility issue between macros written for XLS, XLSX and XLSM? Will the same macro work for all workbooks?

Comment: I think you are confusing people by focusing on the filename rather than mentioning backward compatability between Office versions. If you reword your question you may get more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are significant differences between these formats :

- `.XLS` is intended to be used for Excel 2003 and above, so your VBA code needs to be **backwards compatible** for earlier versions of Excel (<2007)
- `.XLSX` is the Excel 2007 format that **cannot store VBA code**.
- `.XLSM` or `.XLSB` are the Excel 2007 format that allow you to **save VBA code** with the workbook. As Sydenam said, the differences between these two is the way the workbook is stored.

In short: `.XLSB` is the **binary format** (equivalent to `.XLS` for 2007+ version) whereas `.XLSM` is the [**OOXML**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) format.

See [When should the xlsm or xlsb formats be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821632/in-which-case-should-we-use-the-xlsm-or-the-xlsb-format) for more information.

---

Addendum for backward compatibility

I can't see any easy way to tell you how it can be backwards compatible, we can't be *that* generic. You can see on [Ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/search/vba-2007.htm) the new methods and properties that were added in Excel 2007. You can also find [here](http://www.fontstuff.com/ebooks/free/fsExcel2007VBA.pdf) some tips on how to develop on Excel 2007.

The [Ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/search/vba-2007.htm) page will give you the *new elements* of Excel 2007 and then will tell you what you shouldn't use if you wanted to be backwards compatible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer .The question is not difference between various file extension!!!

Comment: I think he's asking more about backwards compatability between Office 2007 and 2003 VBA methods. For example there are new methods and events available in Office 2007 that won't compile in 2003.

Comment: @JP: Damn, thanks. OP's question was really, really unclear... Yet, I've edited my answer to fit this new requirement.

Answer (score 3):

See JMax's response for a list of methods that are unavailable in Excel 2003.

In general, you should write code for the lowest version of Excel you are willing to support. Ex: if you are supporting Excel 2000-2010, your code should be written for Excel 2000.

**Keep in mind, however, that some methods may be deprecated in later versions.**

For example, I would avoid using **FileSearch** altogether (deprecated in Excel 2007) and use **Dir** instead.

Your code should also be testing the local Excel version and using conditional compilation depending on the version.

For help with conditional compilation, see [Using Conditional Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240847%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Also remember that XLSX files cannot save macros. So you should never save files in this format if they contain macro code.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the `FileSearch` function case. MS said it was buggy so they removed it in Excel 2007+, that can be tricky!

Answer (score 1):

Excel uses **Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)** for the macros.  The primary difference between the different file types is how data is stored (**edit & important** XLSX are unable to save Macros, of the formats in the question XLSM and XLS can save macros in the workbook).  It is excel and VBA that handle the macros, so it works no problem between all three of those file formats.

Comment: No, it won't work beween all three formats because `XLSX` **cannot store VBA**

Comment: @JMax Are you suggesting that if I write a macro in an XLSX workbook it will not function?  Just because it can not be stored, does not mean it will not function.

Comment: hmmm... it will work... until you save your workbook in the XLSX format

Comment: Did you just write "XLS are unable to save macros"? Since when are Office 2003 Excel workbooks unable to save and store macro code? Or am I misreading that.

Comment: There's no Excel format "Xlxs". I think you mean "XLSX". JMax is right -- saving an Excel 2007+ workbook in XLSX format will remove any macros in the workbook. Which really has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: I just came back, and I seem to have gone xlsxlsxlsx crazy when I typed that edit! :p