# Reason to not use Excel file format: .xlsb all the time

Tags: excel, file-format

I would like to know if there is a reason to not use .xlsb file format all the time, instead of .xlsx or .xlsm?

I've looked at this post: [When should the xlsm or xlsb formats be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821632/in-which-case-should-we-use-the-xlsm-or-the-xlsb-format)

and also done some basic tests myself, it seems binary format is way superior. So I'm curious to know whether I shouldn't just use .xlsb all the time and say goodbye to .xlsx or .xlsm. Is there a catch somewhere?

Answer (score 8):

The only reason not to use .xlsb is for compatibility reasons since since many other software applications cannot handle the format.