# Excel VBA Workbook.Save Method taking >1 minute for changes on only 1 of 3 worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, performance, save

I have a very odd duck problem with Excel VBA. I have a data file that is opened in VBA, written to and then closed. I have three separate worksheets within this same file that are similar but not the same, but none of them contain shapes, or other objects and relatively small amounts of data (usually less than 1000 rows by no more than 30 columns -- mostly numeric constant values) are being pasted into these worksheets. When two of the sheets are modified, it saves lickety split with no issues, but the third worksheet takes in excess of one minute to complete the save operation. The preceding code is almost exactly the same.

```
    Set WBs = ThisWorkbook
    Set WSs = WBs.Worksheets("SourceData")
    LastRow = WSs.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Finds row number of last row of data

    Set WBd = OpenWorkbook(FileNam, FullPath:=True)
    Set WSd = WBd.Worksheets("TroubledWorksheet")

    ''' CODE FOR COPYING DATA '''
    Set Rng = WSs.Range("A20:AJ" & LastRow + 1) 
    WSd.Range("A2:AJ" & LastRowD).Clear 
    Rng.Copy WSd.Range("A2") 'copies all data from source to dest file

    WSs.Columns("A:AI").Copy 'copy column width from source
    WSd.Columns("A:AI").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths 'paste column width to dest
    
    ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False  'hides zeros in cells if formulas output is zero
    WSd.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete 'clears Conditional Formatting for entire Sheet
    WBd.Activate
    WSd.Select
    WSd.Range("A1").Select

    Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False
    '    WBd.Save
    WBd.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Application.CalculateBeforeSave = True
```

I have uncommented the `.Save` in the above code with the same effect. I have also removed the `.CalculateBeforeSave` flags being set, also with no difference.

`OpenWorkbook` is a helper function that I use to open all of my workbooks.

```vb
''' ***************************************************************************
''' * OpenWorkbook()
''' * Preconditions: None
''' * Input: fname - File name
''' *        show - boolean to show the workbook after opening
''' *        FullPath - Boolean saying wheter it is partial or full path to wb
''' *        Readonly - To open as Read Only or not
''' * Output: The Workbook Object
''' * This returns a workbook object of the specified file name. Checks to see
''' * if the Workbook is already open
''' ***************************************************************************
Public Function OpenWorkbook(fname As String, _
            Optional show As Boolean = True, _
            Optional FullPath As Boolean = False, _
            Optional ReadOnly As Boolean = False, _
            Optional UpdateLinks As Boolean = False, _
            Optional AutoSave As Boolean = False) As Workbook
            
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myFileName As String
    Dim wbPath As String
    Dim aPath() As String
    
    On Error GoTo OpenWorkbookError
    'If GEN_DEBUGGING Then Debug.Print "Enter OpenWorkbook @" & TimeInMS
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    
    wbPath = IIf(FullPath, fname, ReturnPath(fname))
    If Right(wbPath, 4) Like "*xls*" Then
        myFileName = wbPath
    ElseIf Left(fname, 1) = "\" Or Left(fname, 1) = "/" Then
        myFileName = wbPath & Mid(fname, 2) 'SelectFile(wbPath)
    Else
        myFileName = wbPath & fname
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    aPath = Split(myFileName, Delimeter)
    Set wb = Workbooks(aPath(UBound(aPath)))
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myFileName, UpdateLinks:=UpdateLinks, ReadOnly:=ReadOnly)
    On Error GoTo OpenWorkbookError
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 514, "Helper.OpenWorkbook", _
            "Unable to Open " & myFileName & " Workbook"
        Exit Function
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        wb.AutoSaveOn = AutoSave
        On Error GoTo OpenWorkbookError
        wb.Windows(1).Visible = show
    End If
  
    Set OpenWorkbook = wb
    
OpenWorkbookExit:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function
    
OpenWorkbookError:
    MsgBox "Please ensure the workbook you are trying to open is at the specified location: " & _
        vbCrLf & fname, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error Opening Workbook"
    HandleError "Helper.OpenWorkbook()"
    Resume OpenWorkbookExit
End Function
```

This slow save for only one of the sheets has been observed by other members of my company. I have tried to pause the code before the save and save the workbook manually with the same result of a very prolonged save. Once I have saved it the first time it resumes normal behavior and saves quickly either in code or in the Excel application.

Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1: I've updated the code for more completeness

EDIT 2: There was a similar post here: [Too long saving time in Excel via VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975117/too-long-saving-time-in-excel-via-vba) but it resolved itself. The problem I am experience is taking longer and longer. Today it took 11 minutes to save the file. The hangup is only on the .Save everything runs like clockwork right up until that point.

EDIT 3: It appears that some of the time it is now saving quickly and at other times it has continued to act slowly. There is no rhyme or reason behind these differences that I can pinpoint, they all occur when the data file was already created and previously saved, but other than that I am stumped.

EDIT 4: Resurrecting this post because this is becoming a rather serious slow-down in the operation. This behavior is only for Sheet(1) of the 3-sheet workbook, if I save to the other two sheets, this problem is non-existent. If I create a fresh workbook in code (a common occurrence) this problem does not happen, it is only when the data on Sheet(1) is replaced by the new data that we see this problem.  Hopefully someone out there has seen something like this.

Comment: Where are the files located? Locally? OneDrive? Centralised server? And is it always the same file taking a while or always the 3rd in a group of 3 files?

Comment: There's something different abut the 3rd sheet, but it's not easy for us to know what that might be....

Comment: What if OP recreate a new 3rd sheet?

Comment: I apologize for any circumspection, there is nothing substantially different about the 3rd sheet. It has some merged cells, but is otherwise all data. Additionally, when this sheet is originally created this problem does not exist. I might try @RaymondWu's suggestion but it does require that I keep the old data if it exists, so it would require more code. I tried trimming the file with blanks through .UsedRange.Calculate and this did not speed up the process.

Comment: @SamuelEverson they are located on a Microsoft Managed SharePoint site (only used as a file server like OneDrive). This does not seem to be the issue since the save take <5s when saving edits to the other two tabs. All three tabs are always in the file, but when I make edits to one of the tabs is when this delay appears.

Comment: Difficult to make suggestions here - you don't show us much of [what I would think is] the relevant code  - the method you use to update the sheet seems to be somewhat of a suspect here.  On the sheet if you press Ctrl+End does it take you somewhere unexpected?  What is the exact file type?

Comment: @TimWilliams no the Ctrl+End does not take me anywhere unexpected anymore. It was for a while taking me much past the end of the data. But this was corrected through the Sheet.UsedRange.Calculate method. The copy code is all working correctly and quickly it is only the save that hangs up. Here is the relevant copy 
`Set Rng = WSs.Range("A20:AJ" & LastRow + 1)`  
`WSd.Range("A2:AJ" & LastRowD).Clear`  
`Rng.Copy WSd.Range("A2") 'copies all data from source to dest file`

Comment: @TimWilliams I've updated the code above with the complete layout of what is happening.

Comment: I don't see any obvious issues there.  I'm out of ideas.

Comment: The weirdest part is that this same macro has not changed in a very long time and this problem only crept up with the last month or two. It used to save very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

check your strategy for last row

```
LastRow = WSs.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Finds row number of last row of data
```

can return ALL the worksheet, provoking lack of performance

Comment: This does not appear to have any effect as that line of code operates as expected and is quite quick. This problem has disappeared with no change to the code, so I’m not sure what was going on. It was possibly a MS thing wrt OneDrive.