# Creating new worksheet from array

Tags: excel, vba

I have got a worksheet with some data. I store that data in an array and then I want to create a new worksheet and save the data into a new worksheet.

Right now I'm creating a new sheet in the workbook of origin data like this:

```
Sub New_workbook()
   Dim sh as Worksheet, origin as Worksheet, arr
   origin = Sheets("OriginSheet")
   sh = ActiveSheet

   somedata = origin.Range("A1:C").Value

   ReDim arr(1 To 100, 1 To 3)
   
   For i = 1 To 100
      arr(i, 1) = somedata(i, 1)
      arr(i, 2) = somedata(i, 2)
      arr(i, 3) = somedata(i, 3)
   Next i

   sh.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr

End Sub
```

and instead of `sh = ActiveSheet`, I would like to have something like `sh = NewWorkbook("Name_of_new_workbook")` and create a workbook in the directory of `OriginSheet` workbook or given path and fill it with `arr` values. How can I do this in VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to copy all the data in your source range, it isn't necessary to store that data in an array first. Just `Set` your range and make the value of the destination range equal the value of the source range. Try something like this:

```
Sub CopyRangeIntoNewWorkbook()

'disabling screen update and calculation to speed things up
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim wb As Workbook, wb_new As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet

'set the rng for which you want to copy the values
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C10")

'set wb_new to newly added wb
Set wb_new = Workbooks.Add()

'specify the top left cell of the range you want to have populated in the new wb
wb_new.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value2 = rng.Value2

'save file, here using path of your original wb'
wb_new.SaveAs Filename:=wb.path & "\wb_new.xlsx"
'closing the new file
wb_new.Close saveChanges:=False

'enabling screen update and automatic calculation again
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems to work (I still had to work on array, but that was easy to change).

I have 1 question: all of my workbooks are `xlsm` so I changed `xlsx from your code to `xlsm` i got an error that i can't save it as `xlsm`  "with choosen datatype"- what are the differencies between `xlsx` and `xlsm` and how can I create `xlsm` file then?

Comment: Different Excel file formats are discussed here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-excel-0943ff2c-6014-4e8d-aaea-b83d51d46247. You'll need to add the FileFormat if you want to save the new wb as `xlsm`. I.e. write: `wb_new.SaveAs Filename:=wb.Path & "\wb_new.xlsm", FileFormat:=52`. For all codes, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat. In fact, perhaps consider `xlsb` (50): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821632/when-should-the-xlsm-or-xlsb-formats-be-use

Answer (score 0):

The most eficient way to copy a sheet content in a new workbook should be the next one:

```
Sub New_workbook()
   Dim origin As Worksheet
   Set origin = Sheets("OriginSheet") 'an object must be Set
   origin.Copy 'this will create a new workbook with the content of the copied sheet
   ActiveWorkbook.saveas origin.Parent.path & "\" & "Name_of_new_workbook" & ".xlsx", xlWorkbookDefault
End Sub
```

If needing to keep only columns "A:C", you can add the next code lines:

```
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastCol As Long
   Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
   lastCol = sh.cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
   If lastCol <= 3 Then Exit Sub
   If lastCol = 4 Then sh.cells(1, 4).EntireColumn.Delete: Exit Sub
   sh.Range(sh.cells(1, 4), sh.cells(1, lastCol)).EntireColumn.Delete
```